# Will this electric panel pass NC inspection?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, code-compliance, nec

Will this electrical panel pass inspection?  I know there is a 3 foot clearance requirement but not sure if it's an issue here.  This is a replacement panel in an old house that previously had an outdated fire hazard Zinsco circuit breaker panel.  Want to check it will pass inspection before I schedule the inspection.  Located in Wake County NC.

[image: Breaker Panel]

Comment: I’m not a pro but it seems like being right in front of the washer/drier is a big no-no.

Comment: A gas dryer I assume? Makes moving it a bigger challenge.

Comment: I would have a serious chat with whoever did the replacement, leaving it in a spot that would make passing the inspection impossible and _not_ recommending that the dryer be moved. Of course, if that person was me, I'd sit myself down in time out for a good hour to think about what I'd done... :)

Comment: Those look similar to our washer/dryer. I would take down the shelves and stack the washer/dryer away from the panel, then put up smaller shelves.

Comment: @FreeMan Makes me think of my washer/dryer whose corner is lined up with the corner of my electric panel, hah. It's offset so I can stand directly in front of my panel though.

Comment: The thing I've heard is upgrading pre-existing safety problems doesn't cause inspection fails even if they aren't brought up to code. If you would have passed on whatever else you were doing if you left the original panel in, you should still pass after upgrading the panel to a less-hazardous one even if it's not up to code.

Comment: If it were me, I would find a place in the garage to store a washer/dryer pair for a few hours around the time the inspection was scheduled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The clearance requirement is almost definitely going to be an issue. (And not an unusual issue - I will have the same problem if/when I ever upgrade my panel and get it inspected.) The shelves should be OK because you have room to the left. But the washer/dryer (whichever one is closer to the panel) is a definite problem. If there is any way to move it (but still be functional) that would be ideal - even if you move it back the next day for convenience. If it is the dryer, that should be easy. If it is the washer then pipes are likely going to be a problem.

The reason to move it - rather than "wait and see, maybe it will be OK", is that since it is *likely* to be a problem, an inspector who sees it might then start nitpicking on details inside the panel. If you start off "clean" then you have a better chance of sailing through on the rest. As in "What, you dragged me out here when you *knew* that there would be a workspace problem, I'll get you back for wasting my time...". That really could happen.

Answer (score 6):

### No way!

That panel won't pass *any* competent electrical inspection, mostly because the NEC 110.26(A) clear working space has clearly been infringed by the washer/dryer combination.  Not your fault, I know, but as long as that trash? can to the left can find another home, it *should* be possible to move it one stud bay to the left with the aid of some junction and pull boxes for splicing.

Comment: Moving the dryer (say, by putting it on top of the washer after removing some of the shelves) might be way easier than moving the entire panel.

Comment: @TooTea except most dryers aren't wide enough. 36" is needed.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Right, we don't really know how the rest of the room looks like, hence the "might". Perhaps there's room to move the washer a little bit away from the panel as well, perhaps not.